# AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have been using an old versión (April 2010) succesfully and I decided to upgrade to the latest versión (Dec 2013). All .NET.35 (Same as my project)

I have a page that is using a few extenders (Confirm and Autocomplete) that was working fine, the moment that I upgraded the library the page upon displaying keeps reloading in a loop.

I have removed all references to the Control Toolkit and and then it does not do it anymore, but the moment I just introduce the:

The cc1 is defined in the web.config under Pages/Controls as:

With the new library it starts an endless reloading again.

If I put back the .NET35 from April 2010, all works again

Any ideas/suggestions that any of you has heard about this issue?
Thanks
Pete

Comment: May i know what reloading again.

Comment: Reloading again, if this is what you mean, I mean that the page keeps reloading in an endless loop.